# Can an odd perfect number be divisible by $105$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

I have a tough one today.

> Show that if $n$ is an odd perfect number, then not all of $3$, $5$, and $7$ are divisors of $n$.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't think this is known.

Comment: Is this an exercise from somewhere? It's relatively well known that _if_ an odd perfect number $n$ is not divisible by $3,\ 5$ or $7$ then $n$ has a large amount of prime factors, but I'm not aware that your statement holds.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Minor_results) says it's true and gives a reference to a [1949 paper by Kühnel](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02230691). [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPerfectNumber.html) says it's a result by Catalan from 1888.

Comment: @lhf Interesting. The reference provided is dead (even the doi link is broken) but luckily I found [this](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~cvmath/Problem/0610a.pdf) reference which contains a surprisingly compact proof.

Comment: @EuYu, I've given a correct link now.

Comment: Sometimes Google is your best friend.

Comment: Oh, are we supposed to read the question as meaning that no odd perfect number is divisible by all of $3, 5, 7$? That's a rather perverse reading, but it does at least make the claim true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did look at the link, but of course the first thing I thought of was Euler's form of an odd perfect number from which this follows immediately. Euler proved that the prime decomposition $n=q^\alpha p_1^{2e_1}\cdots p_m^{2e_m}$ where $q\equiv \alpha\equiv 1\operatorname{mod} 4$, i.e. a perfect square times one extra prime to a power.

Taking this into account, if $n$ is divisible by $3, 5,$ and  $7$, then $3$ and $7$ must occur to at least the power $2$.

The abundancy index $I(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ gets larger if you increase powers or number of primes (i.e. for any $k>1$, $I(kn)>I(n)$, see Laatsch's [article](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2690424?uid=3739960&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101290859103)).

Thus $2=I(n)>I(5\cdot 3^2\cdot 7^2)=\frac{1+5}{5}\cdot\frac{1+3+3^2}{3^2}\cdot\frac{1+7+7^2}{7^2}>2$, a contradiction.