# Can an odd perfect number be divisible by $101$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, open-problem, perfect-numbers

Preamble - This question is an offshoot from the following earlier questions here at MSE:

[Can an odd perfect number be divisible by 825?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388734)

[Can an odd perfect number be divisible by 165?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400579)

[Odd perfect number divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236891)

My own question is the following:

Can an odd perfect number be divisible by $101$?

Here is my own (quick) attempt at a (partial) answer:

Let $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ be an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form (i.e. $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$).  Also, let
$$N = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
be the canonical (i.e., prime) factorization of $N$.

If $q = 101$, then since
$$(q+1)\mid\sigma(q^k) \mid \sigma(N)=2N,$$
then we have
$$3\cdot17 = 51 = \frac{q+1}{2} \mid N.$$

Thus, it follows that
$$3 \mid N \Longrightarrow 3^2 \mid N,$$
and
$$17 \mid N \Longrightarrow {17}^2 \mid N.$$

Now test:  (Note that $\alpha_i \geq \beta_i, \forall i$.)
$$2 = I(N) \geq \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{p_i} + \ldots + \frac{1}{{p_i}^{\beta_i}}\right)} \geq \frac{102}{101}\cdot\frac{13}{9}\cdot\frac{307}{289} = \frac{407082}{262701} \approx 1.549602019.$$

This is as far as I could go.

Of course, even after establishing $q \neq 101$, we still have to consider the remaining case $101 \mid n \mid N$, whence it follows that ${101}^2 \mid n^2 \mid N$.

Comment: Cohen and Sorli has a paper in Integers (published 2012) titled ["On Odd Perfect Numbers and Even 3-Perfect Numbers"](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/integ.2012.12.issue-6/integers-2012-0036/integers-2012-0036.xml) where they list down some necessary conditions for a prime $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ to be the Euler prime of an odd perfect number $N = {q^k}{n^2}$.

Comment: (Pure pun intended here: If you wish to [quickly] get to the page in Cohen and Sorli's paper where a list of possible Euler primes is presented, just hit CTRL-F and search for $101$.)  =)

Comment: What's the pun?

Comment: Obviously if you have a factor 3^2 but not 3^4, then you also have a factor 13^2. So either a factor 3^4, or a factor 13^2, for some small improvement. Doesn't get that ratio anywhere near 2, so this will be _very_ difficult.