# On the indivisibility of odd perfect numbers by small numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, open-problem, perfect-numbers

A good day to everyone!

This question is an offshoot of the following MSE posts:

[Odd perfect number divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236891)

[Can an odd perfect number be divisible by $101$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468037)

My question is as follows:

> > Is there a positive *ODD* integer $x < 105$ for which it is known that $x$ is *NOT* a divisor
> >
> > of an odd perfect number?

It is to be noted that it's currently unknown whether $3$, $5$ or any prime for that matter does divide an odd perfect number.  On the other hand, it's also currently an open problem to determine if $3 \nmid N$, $5 \nmid N$, etc. holds for an odd perfect number $N$.

Postscript:  Congruence-wise, we know that an odd perfect number $N$ takes one of the following forms:

> > $N \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$; or
> >
> > $N \equiv 81 \pmod{324}$; or
> >
> > $N \equiv 117 \pmod{468}$.

(This is a result due to [Roberts 2008](http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/2008/Sep08/CommsRoberts.pdf).)  Unfortunately, these congruences do not help much with answering this particular question.

Comment: Of course, such integers are known: $2,4,6,\ldots$ ;)

Comment: Ohh yeah, my bad.  Editing my post now to reflect the proper context I had in mind.  Thanks @HagenvonEitzen!

Comment: Posted also on MathOverflow: [Is there an odd integer $x < 105$ for which it is known that $x \nmid N$, if $N$ is an odd perfect number?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/178286)