# Can an odd perfect number be divisible by $5313$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

I know that an odd perfect number cannot be divisible by [$105$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236891/odd-perfect-number-divisors) or [$825$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388734/can-an-odd-perfect-number-be-divisible-by-825). I wonder if that's also the case for $5313$.

Comment: Hint: Note that divisibility by $5313 = 3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot23$ implies divisibility by $3^47^411^4$.

Comment: @RonFord Interesting...

Comment: What kind of [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) is *Anonymous*? :-)

Comment: @Lucian It is a free group that is subject to no relations.

Comment: @RonFord Also note that $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{1}{3^k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{1}{7^k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{1}{11^k}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{23}\right) > 2.$$

Comment: @Librecoin That's more of an answer than a note. You should post it as an answer!

Comment: @RonFord Why is that an answer?

Comment: @Anonymous-agroup I think Librecoin can answer that best!

Comment: @Anonymous-agroup Because the abundancy index of a perfect number must be $2$.

Comment: @Librecoin Thanks.

Comment: Librecoin and Ron Ford, can someone of you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Anonymous-agroup I will give Ron Ford the honor. It was his idea, after all.

Comment: @RonFord You can make a community post if you don't want to take full credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\textbf{Ron Ford}$ already pointed out in the comments, an odd perfect number can be divisible by $5313 = 3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot23$ only if it is divisible by $3^47^411^423$. To see this, use the same line of reasoning as in the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388734/53846).

Continue by noting that

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{1}{3^k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{1}{7^k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{1}{11^k}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{23}\right) > 2,$$

which implies that the abundancy index of the number must be larger than $2$. This contradicts the definition of a perfect number.

Comment: Voted it down because your proof is defective. There is no reason given why 3, 7 and 11 should be raised to the 4th power and not just squared. If you can give a reason then state it. The linked question doesn't give a justification either.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to prove that an odd perfect prime has a factorisation into powers of odd primes, where exactly *one* power is a prime of the form 4k+1, raised to a power 4n+1 (n can be 0), and all the other powers are even. This implies an odd perfect number which is a multiple of $5313 = 3 * 7 * 11 * 23$ must be a multiple of $3^27^211^223^2$. $3^2 7^2 11^2 23^2$ has an abundancy of 1.9037 < 2, so multiples of this number could a priori have an abundance of 2.

However, since $1 + 3 + 9 = 13$, if the number is not a multiple of $3^4$ then it must be a multiple of 13 (it doesn't have to be a multiple of $13^2$ because 13 = 4k+1). Since 1 + 7 + 49 = 57, if the number is not a multiple of $7^4$ then it must be a multiple of 3 (which it is) and of 19, and therefore a multiple of 19^2.

Each of the four possibilities $3^4 7^4 11^2 23^2$, $3^4 7^2 11^2 23^2 19^2$, $3^2 7^4 11^2 23^2 13$ and $3^2 7^2 11^2 23^2 19^2 13$ has an abundancy just above 2, so these numbers and any multiples of them cannot be perfect numbers.

Comment: I have checked the abundancy indices and they are indeed $>2$.