# Can an odd perfect number be divisible by $119$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

We know that an odd perfect number cannot be divisible by $105$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236891)), by $825$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388734)), and by $5313$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768975)).

I wonder if that's also the case for $119$.

Comment: $\sigma_{-1}(119)\approx1.21,$ what makes you think you'd be able to rule this out? Even if 17 isn't the special prime $\sigma_{-1}(2023)\approx1.214$ which is far from 2.