# Possible relationship between non-divisors of odd perfect numbers and coefficients of corresponding cyclotomic polynomials?

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, conjectures, perfect-numbers, open-problem

A positive integer $n$ is called *perfect* if $\sigma(n)=2n$, where
$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d \mid n}{d}$$
is the *sum of divisors* of $n$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then $n$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must have the form $n=p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

It is not known if any *odd* integers $< 100$ divide an odd perfect number.

It is known, however, that:

[An odd perfect number cannot be divisible by 105](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/236920/28816)

[An odd perfect number cannot be divisible by 825](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/394924/28816)

[An odd perfect number cannot be divisible by 5313](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/803791/28816)

We also have the following MSE question:

[Can an odd perfect number be divisible by 165?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400579)

where the accepted answer is that: "An odd perfect number, if one exists, could in principle be divisible by 165."

Note that
$$105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$$
$$825 = 3\cdot {5}^2 \cdot 11$$
$$5313 = 3\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 23$$
and that
$$165 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 11.$$

Now, I am intrigued by a possible relationship of these non-divisors of odd perfect numbers to *coefficients of cyclotomic polynomials*.  Indeed, from the [Wikipedia page on Cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Examples), we have the following penultimate observation:

**The case of the 105th cyclotomic polynomial is interesting because 105 is the lowest integer that is the product of three distinct odd prime numbers (3*5*7) and this polynomial is the first one that *has a coefficient other than 1, 0, or −1*:**

[WolframAlpha computation of the 105th cyclotomic polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=105th+cyclotomic+polynomial)

A similar case holds for the 825th and 5313th cyclotomic polynomials:

[WolframAlpha computation of the 825th cyclotomic polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=825th%20cyclotomic%20polynomial)

[WolframAlpha computation of the 5313th cyclotomic polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5313th%20cyclotomic%20polynomial)

Lastly, we have the following expression for the 165th cyclotomic polynomial:

$$x^{80} + x^{79} + x^{78} - x^{75} - x^{74} - x^{73} - x^{69} - x^{68} - x^{67}$$
$$+ x^{65} + 2x^{64} + 2x^{63} + x^{62} - x^{60} - x^{59} - x^{58} - x^{54}$$
$$- x^{53} - x^{52} + x^{50} + 2x^{49} + 2x^{48} + 2x^{47} + x^{46} - x^{44}$$
$$- x^{43} - x^{42} - x^{41} - x^{40} - x^{39} - x^{38} - x^{37} - x^{36}$$
$$+ x^{34} + 2x^{33} + 2x^{32} + 2x^{31} + x^{30} - x^{28} - x^{27} - x^{26}$$
$$- x^{22} - x^{21} - x^{20} + x^{18} + 2x^{17} + 2x^{16} + x^{15} - x^{13}$$
$$- x^{12} - x^{11} - x^7 - x^6 - x^5 + x^2 + x + 1$$

[WolframAlpha computation of the 165th cyclotomic polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=165th+cyclotomic+polynomial)

I therefore dare to conjecture that:

> **CONJECTURE 1** An odd perfect number $n = p^k m^2$ is not divisible by $165$.
>
> **CONJECTURE 2** An odd perfect number $n = p^k m^2$ is not divisible by an odd number $l$ if the $l$-th cyclotomic polynomial has a coefficient other than $1, 0$, or $-1$.

Alas, I have no proof.  So here is my question:

> Can anybody here (yes, somebody with more computing power) come up with a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sigma(5.3^2.11^2)}{5.3^2.11^2}< 2$$
thus there is no barrier for an odd perfect number divisible by $3,5,11$.

On the other hand $$\frac{\sigma(5.3^2.7^2)}{5.3^2.7^2}> 2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @reuns. (Upvoted as well!)  Would you care to comment more on why "there is no barrier for an odd perfect number divisible by $165$"?  I am sure you are aware of the [factor chain method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414232) of producing consequent factors from an assumed (initial) set of factors for an odd perfect number.